# Wildfly failed to perform hot deploy on Windows

Tags: java, windows, intellij-idea, wildfly, hotswap

When using IntelliJ IDEA 2016.2 + WildFly 8.2.1 Final on OSX(macOS) or Linux(Ubuntu 16.04) with default settings, I can perform hot deploy after these steps:

1. Make your artifact `war exploded`.
2. Enable `Build on make`.
3. Enable `On frame deactivation: Update classes and resources`.

But on my workmates's Windows 10 PC, it just won't work, I digged stackoverflow and `wildfly.org` but I only find some answer suggest me to edit `deployment.xml`: `jsp-config development="true"` and `auto-deploy-exploded="true"`, I tried those without luck.

So how can I get it work?

Comment: Windows can be pretty picky about overwriting content if the file is open, for example WildFly would likely have the file open. I don't have a good answer on how it could be solved though.

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins Thanks for your comment. When I use Windows7+Eclipse several years ago, it worked perfect.